# [Java]- What is wrong with this code?

Tags: java

Print a table of decimal equivalents of all proper fractions with denominators 2 through 14 inclusive with the numerator less than the denominator.  Round the decimal to 5 places.

```
import java.text.*;
public class Decimal 
{
    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        int d;
        int n=1;
        float Sum;
        DecimalFormat Form = new DecimalFormat("0.00000");
        for(d=2;d<=14;d++)
        {
            do
            { 


                Sum= n/d;
               System.out.println(n+"/"+d+"    "+Form.format(Sum));// Problem here I assume,why is the sum always Zero????!!
                             n++;     
           }while(n!=d);
           n=1;


        }

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: well, as long as you don't explain what's it **supposed** to do and what it actually does, it's just a random piece of code. Just a guess, but you're trying to divide 1 (type `int`) by an `int`, which will always result in 0

Comment: Print a table of decimal equivalents of all proper fractions with denominators 2 through 14 inclusive with the numerator less than the denominator.  Round the decimal to 5 places.

Comment: then it's pretty simple: use `1.0/d` instead of `1/d` and the result will be a `double` instead of an `int`. `int` divided by `int` will always result in an integer, thus the fractional digits simply get truncated, always leaving you with 0 in your case

Comment: We are not here to do the homework for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dividing an int by int; the result is an integer. You must cast one of the int to the double data type to get the correct result.

```
Sum = (double)n/d;
```